Laravel 11 Reverb on local network
Does anyone know how to properly set up Laravel Reverb on local network sharing your project via IP:PORT? Other users will be available to listen to the websocket.
My app is running on IP:2020
ws://IP:9909/app/rfqctj66urp5ymorrtjk?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false
pusher-js.js?v=f2fbc5a1:3261 WebSocket connection to 'ws://IP:9909/app/rfqctj66urp5ymorrtjk?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed: 

I tried to run my app with https openssl cert, but it still won't work. Do I need to really host my website?  My requirements are I need to deploy my web on local network only and with websockets.

Did you set allowed_origins per the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/reverb#allowed-origins And are you using --host="0.0.0.0" as instructed?
